# maintain log throughout the session with username and password

Tags: php

i need to maintain log while user login till they signout.I am entering through username and password, this data i need to maintain in separate file with username,password,time and date.and also want to maintain their logout details also.

Comment: It's great that you want to do that. So what have you tried?

Comment: i need an idea to work that

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose there is concept of session variable. read this thing from documentation. set the session variable when user log in. you can use the session variable in all your files and unset it when user call the logout function

ok i unserstood the problem, incorrectly. here is the solution to your problem. 
user jquery for every button or form you are using in html. put an ajax call to the server when there is an action and store it in database or file whatever you like to use
hope it helps

Comment: after user login how to maintain their action

Comment: you want to store what a particular user is doing on your website ?? right?? if i am correct now. please notify

Answer (score 0):

You have two options really.

- Log user actions in a Database.
- Log user actions in a Log file.

The first would have you set up a table that would look something like:

`id | username | action | timestamp | ip | etc etc etc.....`

And on every page visit, you run a database query, whereby you insert a new row with the required information to the database table above.

The second option follows the same principal, except you have a log file for each user whereby you write the `action/timestamp/etc` to said file.

***Note*** This is not the most effective method; as your log files could potentially grow huge, and *"ain't nobody want that"*.